# string manipulation: output the string in reverse without touching the numbers

Tags: string, asp-classic

I have a string input

```
"abc def 50 ghi jhk lmn 63 op qrst"
```

I need to output this string in reverse without touch the numbers

```
"tsrq po 63 nml khj ihg 50 fed cba"
```

I created a vb function

```
function strWords(s,length)
    strWords = ""
    s = replace(s,")"," &#040; ")
    s = replace(s,"("," &#041; ")
    s = replace(s,"-","- ")
    s = replace(s," &#040; "," ( ")
    s = replace(s," &#041; "," ) ")
    dim sArray
    sArray = split(s)
    counter = 0
    for i = 0 to ubound(sArray)
        tempStr = sArray(i)
        counter = counter + len(tempStr)
        if len(tempStr) => 1 then
            if Asc(left(tempStr,1)) => Asc("0") and Asc(left(tempStr,1)) <= Asc("9") then
                strWords = tempStr & " " & strWords
            else
                strWords = StrReverse(tempStr) & " " & strWords
            end if
        end if
        if counter > 20 then 
            strWords =  "<br>" & strWords 
            counter = 0
        end if
    next
end function
```

the problem is that I need to split the string into +-10 char. like this

```
" 50 fed cba" 
"nml khj ihg " 
"tsrq po 63 "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function strWords(s)

    t = ""
    d = ""

    For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If Asc(c) >= Asc(0) And Asc(c) <= Asc(9) Then
            d = c + d
        Else
            t = t + d + c
            d = ""
        End If
    Next

    strWords = t + d

End Function
```

Comment: you can do the rest of the formatting at the end (adding breaks and escaping). I haven't added those to the above code...